# For loop in python 3 (multiple Iteration)

Tags: python

I read a csv file named df, which has 4 columns(id, skill,..) and 30 rows, I want the program to check each id and if the id is "A035755" then print its related skill (j). I wrote the following program it almost works but the problem is it iterates more than once so instead of 30 results I have more than 100!
I think my indexing might be the problem but not sure how to fix it.

Thanks J

```
df=pd.read_csv('location')
for i in df.id[0:len(df)]:  #id is one of the columns
    for j in df.skill:       #skill another column
        if i == "A035755":
            print(j)
        else:
            print("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, df's attributes (df.id, df.skill) represent columns and indexes in the lists (df.id[1..n]) represent rows, then proper way is following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('location')
for index, rec_id in enumerate(df.id):  #id is one of the columns
    if rec_id == "A035755":
        print(df.skill[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can iterate and refrence the index. Like this

```
for index,value in df.id.items():  #id is one of the columns
        if value == "A035755":
            print(df.skill[index])
        else:
            print("Not Found")
```

Or you can iterate on `records`

```
for record in df:
    if record.id == "A035755":
        print(record.skill)
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

Comment: Thanks, But none of the solution works. Actually what the program does, is printing skill column 3 times and then one time "Not found"

Comment: can you add present output and expected output to the question?